# Segmentation fault при внесении данных в статичный массив и при не выполнении условия if

Tags: c, массивы, динамические-массивы

Программа на вход принимает первым аргументом - метод создания массива. Вторым - размер массива и его значения построчно.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NMAX 100
int input(int **a, int n, int m);
void output(int **a, int n, int m);
int input_arr(int *p);
int input_size_arr(int *m, int *n);
int main() {
    int flag = 0;
    int **data = NULL;
    int p, n, m;
    if (input_arr(&p) == 0) {
        if (input_size_arr(&n, &m) == 0) {
            if (p == 1) {
                static int data_stat[NMAX][NMAX];
                data = data_stat;
            }
            if (p == 2) {
                data = (int**)malloc(m*sizeof(int*));
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    data[i] = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
                }
                if (data == NULL) {
                    printf("n/a");
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
            if (p == 3) {
                data = (int**)calloc(m, sizeof(int*));
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    data[i] = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
                }
                if (data == NULL) {
                    printf("n/a");
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
            if (p == 4) {
                data = (int**)realloc(data, m*sizeof(int*));
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    data[i] = (int*)realloc(data[i], n*sizeof(int*));
                }
                if (data == NULL) {
                    printf("n/a");
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0) {
            if (input(data, n, m) == 0) {
                output(data, n, m);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        free(data[i]);
    }
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
int input_arr(int *p) {
    int flag = 0;
    char c;
    if (scanf("%d%c", p, &c) != 2 || c != '\n') {
        printf("n/a");
        flag = 1;
    } else if ((*p > 4 || *p < 1) && flag == 0) {
        printf("n/a");
        flag = 1;
    }
    return flag;
}
int input_size_arr(int *m, int *n) {
    int flag = 0;
    char c;
    if (scanf("%d%c", m, &c) != 2 || c != ' ') {
        printf("n/a");
        flag = 1;
    } else if ((scanf("%d%c", n, &c) != 2 || c != '\n') && flag == 0) {
        printf("n/a");
        flag = 1;
    } else if ((*n > 100 || *m > 100 || *n < 2 || *m < 2) && flag == 0) {
        printf("n/a");
        flag = 1;
    }
    return flag;
}
int input(int **a, int n, int m) {
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    while (i2 < m) {
        while (i < n-1) {
            if (flag == 1) break;
            if (scanf("%d%c", &a[i2][i], &c) != 2 || (c != ' ')) {
                printf("n/a");
                flag = 1;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
        i = 0;
        if (flag == 0) {
            if (scanf("%d%c", &a[i2][n-1], &c) != 2 || c != '\n') {
                printf("n/a");
                flag  = 1;
            }
        }
        i2++;
    }
    return flag;
}

void output(int **a, int n, int m) {
    int i = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    int min = 99999999;
    int max = 0;
    while (i2 < m) {
        while (i < n-1) {
            printf("%d ", a[i2][i]);
            i++;
        }
        printf("%d", a[i2][n-1]);
        printf("\n");
        i = 0;
        i2++;
    }
    i = 0;
    i2 = 0;
    while (i2 < m) {
        while (i < n) {
            if (a[i2][i] > max) max = a[i2][i];
            i++;
        }
        printf("%d ", max);
        i = 0;
        i2++;
        max = 0;
    }
    printf("\n");
    i2 = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (i2 < m) {
        min = 99999999;
        while (i < n) {
            if (a[i][i2] < min) min = a[i][i2];
            i++;
        }
        if (i2 < m-1) printf("%d ", min);
        i = 0;
        i2++;
    }
    printf("%d", min);
}
```

В первом случае ошибка вылезает при занесении данных в статичный массив, за это отвечает функция `input(int **a, int n, int m)`. При работе с выделением динамической памяти все работает, а с массивом нет. Объявляется он в `main` и присваивается указателю в строке 16. Пробовал выносить за main, и делать static int.

Во втором случае, в функции `input_size_arr(int *m, int *n)` идет проверка в строке 82 на размер введенных значений, если условие else if выполняется, то выдает segmentation fault, вместо вывода на экран n/a по условию.

Answer (score 0):

Тип `static int data_stat[NMAX][NMAX];` несовместим с `int **data = NULL;`. Математика вычисления позиций элементов совсем разная. `data_stat` содержит только типы `int`, а `data` - это массив указателей на массивы `int`.

```
& data_stat[i][j] == & data_stat[0][0] + i * sizeof ( int[NMAX])
  + j * sizeof(int)

& data[i][j] == data[i] + j * sizeof(int)
```

При присваивании указателей `data = data_stat;` и попытке доступа к элементам происходит ошибка неправильного доступа к памяти, так как компилятор думает, что там указатель, а там числа.

Решением будет **не** использовать статический массив `static int data_stat[NMAX][NMAX];`. А всегда создавать с помощью `malloc`.

---

Ещё у вас ошибка выделения памяти. Вы выделяете память под массив указателей, а надо под числа. А также выделяете память под `m` строк, а указателей пишете `n` штук.

```
data = (int**)malloc(m*sizeof(int*));

for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
   data[i] = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int * ));                              
                    v                  v
for (int i = 0; i < m ; i++) {
  data[i] = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int    ));
```